# Platform Error when attempting to write to nfc tag

Tags: flutter, nfc, ndef

im working on NFC using the nfc_manager package and mifare classic tags. On my onTagDiscovered method i call the following write method:

```
Future<void> _ndefWrite(NfcTag tag) async {

    final ndef = Ndef.from(tag);

    final formattable = NdefFormatable.from(tag);



    final message = NdefMessage([

      NdefRecord.createText('1'), // ID

      NdefRecord.createText('John'), // Name

      NdefRecord.createText('Doe'), // Surname

    ]);



    if (ndef != null) {

      if (!ndef.isWritable) {

        showErrorNotification(

            context: context, errorMessage: 'This tag is not writable.');

      }



      final tech = MifareClassic.from(tag);



      if (tech == null) {

        log('Tag is not Mifare Classic');

      }



      //define a list of access key A

      final listKeyDefault = [

        0xff,

        0xff,

        0xff,

        0xff,

        0xff,

        0xff,

      ];

      final dataKeyDefault = Uint8List.fromList(listKeyDefault);



      //define the data you want to write

      const String fullName = 'Sakhanya swartbooi';

      //encode the the data as  Uin8List

      final Uint8List data = utf8.encode(fullName) as Uint8List;



      try {

        tech?.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(sectorIndex: 2, key: dataKeyDefault);

        tech?.authenticateSectorWithKeyB(sectorIndex: 2, key: dataKeyDefault);



        await ndef.write(message);

        log('Successfully wrote to the Mifare Classic EV1 tag');

      } on PlatformException catch (e) {

        log(e.message ?? 'Some error has occurred.');

      } on Exception catch (e) {

        log(e.toString() ?? 'Some error has occurred.');

      }

    } else if (formattable != null) {

      try {

        final tech = MifareClassic.from(tag);



        if (tech == null) {

          log('Tag is not Mifare Classic');

        }



        //define a list of access key A

        final listKeyDefault = [

          0xff,

          0xff,

          0xff,

          0xff,

          0xff,

          0xff,

        ];

        final dataKeyDefault = Uint8List.fromList(listKeyDefault);

        tech?.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(sectorIndex: 2, key: dataKeyDefault);

        tech?.authenticateSectorWithKeyB(sectorIndex: 2, key: dataKeyDefault);

        await formattable.format(message);

      } on PlatformException catch (e) {

        log(e.toString());

        showErrorNotification(

            context: context, errorMessage: e.message.toString());

      }

    }

  }
```

When i hit the ndef.write line i get PlatformException (PlatformException(invalid_parameter, Tag is not found, null, null)), how can i fix this? The tag itself is writable and its empty, i tested it out first by using the NFC Tools app.

Comment: An **empty** Mifare classic tag may be writable, but to use Ndef-technology you need to format the tag before yo can write on them with Ndef. There should be a document available how to prepare a tag for NDEF (anthing with AN...).

Comment: As Michael says implementation of the MifareClassic class is optional on Android but if it is supported then Ndef support on Mifare Classic must be supported (but some phones do not support Mifare Classic), so if a Mifare Classic is not natively supported by a particular phone then you have to work at the lower NfcA level directly and format/read the Tag yourself at the lower level. On iOS I believe it will always support Mifare Classic and Ndef storage on Mifare Classic. Generally it's best to avoid the proprietary (non NFC standard Type) Mifare Classic Tags if you can for best compatibility.